# D3.js: how to find Average grouped by Year and Month?

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js

I am trying to find the monthly average of all the values(i.e. duration here) linked to all the activities(i.e. fetched in keys) with respect to their year.

My csv is like:

```
ID      TEST_DATE     TEST_DURATION    TEST_ACTIVITY
10000   1/1/2014 0:00   4              Electricity Bill Payment
10001   1/2/2014 0:00   1              Water Bill Payment
10002   1/3/2014 0:00   2              Gas Bill Payment
10003   1/4/2014 0:00   1              Electricity Bill Payment
10001   1/2/2014 0:00   1              Water Bill Payment
10001   1/2/2014 0:00   1              Water Bill Payment
14878   9/12/2016       6              Statement Request
```

My code is as follows:

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function(error,data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            //console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(d.TEST_DATE));
            a = d.TEST_DATE.split(" ",1);
            b=a[0].split("/");
            f_date = b[0].concat("-").concat(b[1]).concat("-").concat(b[2]);
            console.log(d.f_date);          
            console.log(f_date); 
             var date = new Date(f_date);
             var day = date.getDay();
            var month = date.getMonth()+1;
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            console.log("Day:"+day+" ,Month:"+month+" ,Year:"+year); 

            if(data.TEST_ACTIVITY == keys){
                console.log("check:"+keys);
                groupByMonth = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d){return year; })
                .key(function(d) {return month; })
                .rollup(function(v) { return d3.mean(v, function(d) { return d.TEST_DURATION; }); })
                .entries(data);
                console.log("Grouped Values by Month::"+JSON.stringify(groupByMonth));
            }   

            //finding the count of no. of ids per activity using Test_ID
        countByActivties=  d3.nest()
           .key(function(d) { return d.TEST_ACTIVITY; })
          .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
          .entries(data);
        console.log("Count of activities based on test-id::"+JSON.stringify(countByActivties));

        //sorting the data in descending order and find the top keys
        keys = countByActivties
        .sort(function(a, b){return b.values-a.values})
        .slice(0,6)
        .map(function(d){ return d.key;})
        console.log("Keys::"+keys);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Grouped Values by Month::[{"key":"2016","values":[{"key":"9","values":2.2857142857142856}]}]
```

Its output for example should be like:

```
Grouped Values by Month::[{"key":"2016","values":[{"key":"9","values":6}]}]
```

and rest the same for other months as well.

Any idea??

Comment: Where is `year` defined in  `.key(function(d){return year; })` ?

Comment: Uh? The previous version was closer to being correct than this one, you've got an overall structure problem right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer was for the first version of the code]

Assuming that your first parsing function works as expected, you should remember the date fields directly in your data. Feel free to change the field names.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
        a = d.TEST_DATE.split(" ",1);
        b=a[0].split("/");
        f_date = b[1].concat("-").concat(b[0]).concat("-").concat(b[2]);
        //NEW LINES: add year, month and day fields to the data (*1 to convert to number)
        d.year = b[2]*1;
        d.month = b[0]*1;
        d.day = b[1]*1;
        console.log(d.TEST_DATE);           
        console.log(f_date);        
    })
```

then ...

```
    groupByMonth = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){return d.year; }) //NB: use "d.year", not "year"
    .key(function(d) {return d.month; }) // idem with month
    .rollup(function(v) { return d3.mean(v, function(d) { return d.TEST_DURATION; }); })
    .entries(data);
    })
```

I don't understand how the `keys` array is supposed to be used, there might be another problem, different from your question, with your `data.forEach(function(keys){...})`.

Comment: ... with some differences (see "NEW LINES" and "NB"). If you set up a jsfiddle with the first version I could show the difference...